# Why do I get a ReferenceError when accessing member variables from a member function directly?

Tags: javascript

I am puzzled and trying to understand this...

In OO languages like C++ and Java, a member function of an object can refer to a member variable directly.

However in the object below, if a member function refers to property 'balance' directly,

`balance += amount;` I get error

```
ReferenceError: balance is not defined
```

One has to qualify fully, `savingsAccount.balance`

Why is that so?

```
var savingsAccount = {
    balance: 1000,
    interestRatePercent: 1,
    deposit: function addMoney(amount) {
        if (amount > 0) {
            balance += amount; <<--==-ERROR---====--ERROR---=====--- ERROR!
        }
    },
    withdraw: function removeMoney(amount) {
        var verifyBalance = savingsAccount.balance - amount;
        if (amount > 0 && verifyBalance >= 0) {
            savingsAccount.balance -= amount;
        }
    },
    printAccountSummary: function print() {
        return 'Welcome!\nYour balance is currently $' + savingsAccount.balance +' and your interest rate is '+ savingsAccount.interestRatePercent + '%.';
    }
};

console.log(savingsAccount.printAccountSummary());
```

Comment: `balance` is a property of the object, not a standalone variable

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I am accessing it from `addMoney`, also a property.

Comment: Yes, and to access it you have to treat it as a property, which is what it is.  Hence the fully-qualified reference.

Comment: this is very different from other OO languages. I don't understand this behavior.

Comment: Not so different.  `Balance` has been declared inside `savingsAccount,` so it is locally-scoped to that object.  `Balance` doesn't exist outside `savingsAccount`.

Comment: Slightly off topic but if you're more comfortable with OOP focused languages, I would highly recommend using javascript [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: Note that `deposit` has its own scope.  Yes, Javascript is a weird language.  Always has been.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but my point is that addMoney is also declared inside savingsAccount and since these properties are both member variables or properties, they should be able to access each other directly. I dont know why my question is downvoted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit member variables are shorthand for `this.member` (or `this->member` in C++). Javascript does not have implicit member variables, so you must always prefix member variables with `this.`

```
class SavingsAccount {
    constructor() {
        this.balance=1000;
        this.interestRatePercent=1;
    }
    deposit(amount) {
        if (amount > 0) {
            this.balance += amount;
        }
    }
    withdraw(amount) {
        var verifyBalance = this.balance - amount;
        if (amount > 0 && verifyBalance >= 0) {
            this.balance -= amount;
        }
    }
    printAccountSummary() {
        return 'Welcome!\nYour balance is currently $' + this.balance +' and your interest rate is '+ this.interestRatePercent + '%.';
    }
}
savingsAccount = new SavingsAccount();
savingsAccount.deposit(100);
console.log(savingsAccount.printAccountSummary());
savingsAccount.withdraw(200);
console.log(savingsAccount.printAccountSummary());
```